# PHP DOM accessing the object with same attribute

Tags: php, regex, dom, domdocument

I want to get the date object text content and Team 1. But Team 2 object has the same attribute option with date object. How can I get the right content? If I echo $date I get date value with Team2... How should I write conditions?

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding=2 cellspacing=0 id="tblFixture" border=0>
    <tr class=row1 align=center side='home'>
        <td align=left>21.09.1928</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td align='right'><span class='team'>Team 1</span></td>
        <td align=left><a href='http://www.foo.com/bar' target='_blank'>Team 2</a></td>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

PHP Code:

```
$url = "http://www.bla.com/bla.html";
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nlig  = $xpath->query('//table[@id="tblFixture"]/tr[@side=\'home\']');

$i = 0;
foreach ($nlig AS $val)
{
    $date       = $xpath->query('//table[@id="tblFixture"]/tr[@side=\'home\'][@class=\'row1\']/td[@align=\'left\']')->item($i)->textContent;
    $first_team = $xpath->query('//table[@id="tblFixture"]/tr[@side=\'home\']/td[@align=\'right\']/span[@class=\'team\']')->item($i)->textContent;

    echo $date, $first_team, "<br />";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: What does `But Team 2 object has the same attribute option with date object` means?

Comment: <td align=left>21.09.1928</td> <td align=left><a href='http://www.foo.com/bar' target='_blank'>Team 2</a></td>
                </td>
Both of are has align=left...

Comment: You're using the `align` attribute as a label for your data?  No.  Give it a `class` or an `id`.

Comment: i get the data from a remote url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to validate / find the date.

Something like:

```
preg_match("/<td align=left>([0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4})<\/td>/", $html, $matches);
```

Comment: I've no more experience with regexp. But if I get some regexp rule like: "clear everything without number and comma" and use with preg_replace function I will have the right answer...

Comment: In my previous exemple, you'll have the date stored in $matches[1] Isn't it what you're looking for?